# .NET MVC error in EditorTemplate calling another EditorTemplate

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I have a Aviewmodel that contains a child SignViewModel.
and a Bviewmodel that also contains a child SignViewModel.

***AViewModel***:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
//nav props
public virtual SignViewModel signVm { get; set; }
```

***BViewModel***:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
//nav props
public virtual SignViewModel signVm { get; set; }
```

***SignViewModel***:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string cert { get; set; }
public string pwd { get; set; }
//nav props
public virtual AViewModel aVm { get; set; }
public virtual BViewModel bVm { get; set; }
```

---

Then I have an editorTemplate for SignViewModel, that simply shows the 2 html fields:

***EditorTemplates/SignViewModel.cshtml***:

```
@Model MyProject.ViewModels.SignViewModel
@EditorFor(m => m.cert)
@EditorFor(m => m.pwd)
```

and also for AViewModel and for BViewModel:

***EditorTemplates/AViewModel.cshtml***:

```
@Model MyProject.ViewModels.AViewModel
@EditorFor(m => m.name)
...
@EditorFor(m => m.signVm)
```

***EditorTemplates/BViewModel.cshtml***:

```
@Model MyProject.ViewModels.BViewModel
@EditorFor(m => m.name)
...
@EditorFor(m => m.signVm)
```

---

This is working nicely.
But now I need to change it so that in BViewModel.cshtml, instead of just including the SignViewModel editorTemplate, I need to have a bootstrap modal, and inside it, the SignViewModel.
so I have created another EditorTemplate, SignModalViewModel:
***EditorTemplates/SignModalViewModel.cshtml***:

```
@Model MyProject.ViewModels.SignViewModel
<div class="modal">
    ....
        @EditorFor(m => m)  --> this should load here EditorTemplate SignViewModel... but its not...
    ....
</div>
```

and I modified BViewModel.cshtml:
***EditorTemplates/BViewModel.cshtml***:

```
@Model MyProject.ViewModels.BViewModel
@EditorFor(m => m.name)
...
@EditorFor(m => m.signVm, "SignModalViewModel")
```

but this is not working: AViewModel.cshtml works ok, but BViewModel.cshtml shows an empty modal... so it seems the line @EditorFor(m => m) (in SignModalViewModel.cshtml) is not working (I guess it does not find EditorTemplates/SignModalViewModel.cshtml)

what am I doing wrong??